grid how to remove column mesh
How can I remove vertical column mesh (space) from columns using display grid? Here is the grid layout I'm using:
display: grid;
grid-template-column: repeat(2, 1fr);

I'm getting a space between items in the same row, and I'd like to collapse that space, as shown in the pictures below.

Grid Layout

I'd like to go from this:

To this:


That's no longer a grid, and won't work with CSS Grid

This currently doesn't work in grid. You'd need to use flexbox and flex-wrap. Something like this:


.sizes {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 8px;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 200px;
}

.size {
  background: lightgray;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
}
<div>
  <ul class="sizes">
    <li class="size">X-Small</li>
    <li class="size">Small</li>
    <li class="size">Medium</li>
    <li class="size">Large</li>
    <li class="size">X-Large</li>
    <li class="size">XX-Large</li>
    <li class="size">3X Large</li>
    <li class="size">4X Large</li>
  </ul>
</div>



Eventually, grid will be getting a masonry option that would come close to something like this, but grid isn't the right solution as it keeps things in a grid. flexbox is the way to go.

Good answer. But even down the road, masonry won't make this possible with grid.

@Sean, you are correct to an extent. Using Safari Technical Preview, take a look at this codepen example. You'll notice that it does work, but the using masonry in the column direction forces the auto-flow to be column. So yes, masonry wouldn't handle this and flexbox is better, but it "can" do it. Make sure to check out the WebKit masonry demos.
